# Generic type in a list of functions

Tags: haskell

I have the next structures:

```
data BasicTypes = TypeS String 
                | TypeI Integer
                deriving (Show, Ord, Eq)

data MRF = MRF {
    lastValue :: BasicTypes,
    requestedFilters :: [RF]
} deriving (Show)

data RF = RF {
    event :: String,
    filters :: [Filter]
} deriving (Show)

type BooleanFunction  a = a -> Bool
data Filter = Filter {
    operation :: BooleanFunction BasicTypes,
    value :: BasicTypes
} deriving (Show)
```

I want to have a MRF data, that contains a list of requestedFilters (RF). Each RF have filters, and those filters can be of a String or an Integer type.

The thing is that the filters are created dynamically and could be either about a String or an Integer value, so we could have:

```
Filter1 = Filter {operation = (==) 5, value = 3} 
Filter2 = Filter {operation = (==) "hello", value = "hello"}
```

And both filters been included in the same MRF!

I want to avoid the BasicTypes data, and put a generic type, but If a put `operation :: a -> Bool` then all the Filter should be of the same type (so I can't have things like `Integer -> Bool` and `String -> Bool` together in the same list).

What do you suggest to do so? Thanks!

PS: I already tried with the TypeRep type, but I couldn't find a solution for this

Comment: And what should happen if `Filter1` is applied to an String, or `Filter2` to an Integer? It doesn't make sense to have a heterogeneous list of filters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this work for you?

```
data Filter a = Filter { operation :: a -> Bool, value :: a }

data RF a = RF { event :: String; filters :: [ Filter a ] }

data MRF a = MRF { lastValue :: a, requestedFilters :: [RF a] }
```

In an `RF a`, all of the filters have to be of type `Filter a`.

**Update**

> I want to have a list of filters for Strings in a RF, then have another RF with a list of Integer, then other RF with a list of Floats, and so on. And I want all those RF in a list (MRF).

How about this:

```
data MFRList = MRFList
             { integerMRFs    :: [ MRF Integer ]
             , stringMRFs     :: [ MRF String ]
             , floatMRFs      :: [ MRF Float ]
             }
```

Add as many fields as you need.

Comment: Ok, but in the MRF can I have RFs with diferent filters?

Comment: The real question is what do you want to do with an MRF? What do you expect to happen if you try to apply a Filter for Integers to a String? Can you show what you are trying to accomplish in another language?

Comment: I want to have a list of filters for Strings in a RF, then have another RF with a list of Integer, then other RF with a list of Floats, and so on. And I want all those RF in a list (MRF). This will give to the MRF data flexibility in the input, am I clear?
If I do what you suggest then I'll have a MRF with a list of ONLY one type :/
Have you another idea?

Comment: But why do you want to have an MRF Integer and an MRF String in the same list? Write some code (even pseudo code) which makes use of such a list so we can see what you are trying to accomplish, and we might be able to offer some alternatives.

Comment: Today I'll check your solution @ErikR and I'll let you know. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

The basic solution to this is to use two constructors for `Filter`:

```
data Filter 
    = FilterI {
    operationI :: Int -> Bool,
    valueI :: Int
    } 
    | FilterS {
    operationS :: String -> Bool,
    valueS :: String
    }
```

A more advanced alternative, using GADTs:

```
-- singleton
data BasicType t where
   BasicI :: BasicType Int
   BasicS :: BasicType String

data Filter where
   Filter ::
      { ty :: BasicType t
      , operation :: t -> Bool
      , value :: t
      } -> Filter
```

Note that above it is important that the field `ty` can be tested at runtime so that we can discover which type `t` actually is. Example:

```
useFilter :: Filter -> Int
useFilter (Filter BasicI op v) = v         -- we know it's Int
useFilter (Filter BasicS op v) = length v  -- we know it's String
```

We could also avoid GADTs and use plain existential types, only:

```
data Filter where
   Filter ::
      { operation :: t -> Bool
      , value :: t
      } -> Filter
```

but in this way, `Filter` is actually isomorphic to `Bool`: there's nothing we can do with `value` except to use it as an argument to `Filter`. Hence here a list of filters is simply a list of booleans, which is uninteresting.

In general, if you are using a list of existential types, you might be using a known [antipattern](https://lukepalmer.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/haskell-antipattern-existential-typeclass/).